# Get extended properties from files

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to get extended file properties from video files in the folder the script is ran from and output results to a text file.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Dim ls, fsObj, fd, fs, fl, sfs, sf, tf

    ' specify the file extensions to list
    dim fileTypes
    fileTypes = Array("mp4","mkv","avi")

 On Error Resume Next

    ls = ""
    Set fsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fd = fsObj.GetFolder(".")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(fsObj)
    set fs = fd.Files

For Each fileName in objFolder.Items
    set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fileName)
    size = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 1)
    length = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 27)
    height = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 283)
    width  = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 285)
Next


    ' list subfolders
    set sfs = fd.SubFolders
    For Each sf in sfs
        ls = ls & sf.name & vbCrLf & chr(10)
    Next

        For Each fl in fs
        ' check whether the extension matches 
        if arrayContains(fileTypes, fsObj.GetExtensionName(fl.name))then
    ls = ls & fl.name & vbtab & length & vbCrLf & chr(10)

        end if
    Next
    Set tf = fsObj.OpenTextFile("index.txt", 2, True, False)

    tf.Writeline ls

    tf.Close
    Set fsObj = Nothing

    function arrayContains (arr, val)            
        dim found
        found = false
        for i = 0 to ubound(arr)
            if arr(i) = val then    
                found = true
                exit for 
            end if
        next
        arrayContains = found            
    end function
```

I'm trying to get the file name and length once I can get that I can add the others.

As far as I can guess I need to specify objFolder.ParseName(fileName). How do I specify all files that match the filetypes array? I have tried fl.name and fd.files. I don't know what else to try.

I'm running the script by double clicking the vbs file from windows explorer in windows 7.

The script runs with no errors and returns the file names, but doesn't return the extended properties. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, get rid from this statement `On error resume next` and re-execute this script and tell us what did you get as error until now ?

Comment: I did that and got line 40 char 5 Permission denied.

Comment: Well I tried some code on my system and it works, but only for the mp4 files. For flv, avi, mkv, I was only able to retrieve their size(but not the length, frame height and width). I can share the code if you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code is able to get the details like name, size, length, frame height and frame width for the mp4 files. For the files of formats flv, avi, mkv, it is only able to extract their name and size. For these files, even when you right-click on them, select properties and go to the Details tab, you won't see the information about their length, height and width. But for mp4, you get to see all these details.

Try this code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set obs = CreateObject("shell.application")
Set fol = fso.GetFolder(".")
Set spl = obs.NameSpace(fol.Path)
Set files = fol.Files
filePath = fol.path&"\Info.txt"
set objFile = fso.openTextFile(filePath,2,true,true)

arr = Array("mp4", "mkv", "avi", "flv")

For Each file In files
    ext = fso.GetExtensionName(file.Name)
    For Each ex In arr
        If StrComp(ext,ex,1)=0 Then
            objFile.writeline "NAME: "&spl.GetDetailsOf(spl.ParseName(file.Name),0)&vbcrlf&_
                              "SIZE: "&spl.GetDetailsOf(spl.ParseName(file.Name),1)&vbcrlf&_
                              "LENGTH: "&spl.GetDetailsOf(spl.ParseName(file.Name),27)&vbcrlf&_
                              "FRAME HEIGHT: "&spl.GetDetailsOf(spl.ParseName(file.Name),283)&vbcrlf&_
                              "FRAME WIDTH: "&spl.GetDetailsOf(spl.ParseName(file.Name),285)&vbcrlf&string(50,"==")
            Exit For
        End If  
    Next

Next
objFile.Close
set objFile = Nothing
set files = nothing
set spl = nothing
set fol = nothing
set obs = nothing
set fso = nothing
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Would it be hard to make it write to a file? Sorry I'm quite new to vbs.

Comment: @SimoneM I have updated the code. All the Information will now be written to a text file called "Info.txt" in the same folder

Comment: That's almost perfect. I've been playing with it and one of the other properties I want is bit rate. Just as a quick test I changed the 283 in frame height to 28 and got an error: Invalid procdure call or argument.

Comment: Sorry, my fault I must have messed up when I changed the 283 to 28 because it works fine now. You are a life saver. I've been trying to this for about a week now. Again thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Cool. I was about to work on that. You are welcome :)

Comment: the script is working great thank you, one more question though if you don't mind. Is it easy to get it to list any subfolders that are in the directory as well? I'm just after the folder names not the contents. preferably in a seperate loop. I've tried a few things, but don't have the knowledge yet.

Comment: Just use the [Subfolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/subfolders-property) property.